# Select buttons bound to same scope, triggering each other on click. How to unbind scope from two select list buttons in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hQHN/23/)

Clicking on one button triggers the other.  In my app, clicking on categories changes the url to /:catId, to populate the animals list where animal.catId = catId. I have tried putting the arrays behind functions/objects but one still triggers the other.  It seems that the buttons are both pointing to the same object in the scope or model but how do I separate them? Seems too convenient not to process both lists in the same factory.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Categories<span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li ng-repeat="category in animals.categories"><a>{{category}}</a></li>
       </ul>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Animals <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
           <li ng-repeat="category in animals.all"><a>{{animal}}</a></li>
       </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('animals', function(){
       var data = 
        [
            {category: "mammal", name: "dog", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "fish", name: "pickerel", categoryID: "FIS"},
    {category: "mammal", name: "cat", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "mammal", name: "monkey", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "bird", name: "budgie", categoryID: "BIRD"}
        ];

   var collect_categories = function(o, e) {
    o[e.categoryID] = e.category;
    return o;
};
var unpack = function(name, id) {
    return { name: name, catID: id };
};


    var all = [];
    var categories = [];

    var init = function() {

         _(data).each(function(item) {
             all.push({
             title: item.name,
             })
         });

          _(data).chain()
             .reduce(collect_categories, {})
             .map(unpack)
          .each(function(cat) { categories.push(cat)})
             .value();

    }();

    return {
        all: all,
        categories: categories
    }
});


function MyCtrl($scope, animals){
    console.log("animals", animals);
    $scope.animals = animals;

}


MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'animals'];
```

Comment: you are trying to use bootstrap.js on top of angular...use directives like angular-ui instead. Using other self initalizing DOM manipulation frameworks on top of angular is a bad idea, and doesn't work

Comment: @charlietfl That's not true, i've successfully used Bootstrap 3 on top of AngularJS along with Angular-ui.

Comment: @m.e.conroy perhaps if you know the nuances of each can work with it, howver in genral unless understand how angular manipulates DOM it is best practice to use directives to do your own manipulation ..can certainly call other framework from a directive, but expecting one that initializes on page load to work after angular does it's DOM changes is not a good idea

Comment: @charlietfl I agree that directives are the place to manipulate the dom but in this case its not necessary, Bootstrap is just using CSS and a bit of data toggling to create a button with a drop down.  It doesn't interfere with Angular controller operation at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/9hQHN/24/

**UPDATE**: Here's a fiddle with the dropdowns filled out: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/9hQHN/25/

Cliff you had both buttons in the same bootstrap button group, the toggle will open both drop downs when that happens.  You need to separate them into two different button groups

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Categories<span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li ng-repeat="category in animals.categories"><a>{{category}}</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Animals <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li ng-repeat="category in animals.all"><a>{{animal}}</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

<strike>There is something wrong with your service however, I don't think you're giving the controller the correct data in `animals` in order to see the correct categories in the drop down</strike>

Comment: @CliffCoulter Here's an example with having selected a category: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/9hQHN/26/